# Returning name along with foreign key ID in Laravel

Tags: php, json, database, laravel

This API route is working fine and returning JSON response, currently it is returning `category_id` as a foreign key, I also want to get column 'name' from table 'category' in my JSON response, how to do it? Help shall be appreciated.

```
Route::get('/quizzes', function() {

$quizzes = App\Quiz::select('id','name','description','average_playtime','status','image','thumbnail','created_at','updated_at','category_id','user_id','category_name'

  DB::raw('created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 day) as isNew')                           

                    )->where('status', 'active')->take(20)->get();        

   return Response::json(array(
        'error' => false,

        'quizzes' => $quizzes,
        'status_code' => 200
    ));


 });
```

Comment: use join to get the data from `category` able based on `category_id`

Comment: can u plz explain ..

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#joins

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a really trivial problem. Have you read *any* simplest tutorials at all? This is not a code-writing service. Please learn the technology basics before you come ask questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Join to table category and get the category_name

```html
Route::get('/quizzes', function() {
  $quiz = new App\Quiz();

  $selectClause = array(
                    $quiz.getTable().'id',
                    $quiz.getTable().'name',
                    $quiz.getTable().'description',
                    $quiz.getTable().'average_playtime',
                    $quiz.getTable().'status',
                    $quiz.getTable().'image',
                    $quiz.getTable().'thumbnail',
                    $quiz.getTable().'created_at',
                    $quiz.getTable().'updated_at',
                    $quiz.getTable().'category_id',
                    $quiz.getTable().'user_id',
                    'c.category_name',
                    DB::raw($quiz.getTable().'created_at >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 day) as isNew')
                  );
                  
  $quizzes = App\Quiz::join('category AS c', 'c.category_id', '=', $quiz.getTable().'category_id')
                     ->select($selectClause)
                     ->where('status', 'active')
                     ->take(20)
                     ->get();
                     
   return Response::json(array(
              'error' => false,
              'quizzes' => $quizzes,
              'status_code' => 200
          ));
});
```